# SQL convert dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS to MM/dd/yyyy

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, datetime-format

How can I convert `'11-09-2012 5:08:31 PM'` to `'09/11/2012'`? (From `dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:SS` to `MM/dd/yyyy`).

Date is `11 September 2012`.
Or is there any way to convert this in C#? But in C# I want only date not string.

Comment: Which SQL? SQL Server, MySQL.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx

Comment: use DateTime.Parse() method to convert from string

Comment: You want to convert a string to another string but want _"only date not string"_?

Comment: @JesseJames it will return me date with time, I want it to return date and in MM/dd/yyyy format only

Comment: use DateTime's ToString with pattern "MM/dd/yyyy": date.ToString("MM/dd/yyyy")

Comment: @LajjaThaker what version of sql-server?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using **SQL Server** query:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, '11-09-2012 5:08:31 PM', 101);
```

This will convert in `MM/dd/yyyy`.For more info see [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) and [How to convert from string to datetime?](http://www.sqlusa.com/bestpractices/datetimeconversion/)

---

To convert using **C#**.

You can do that like this:

```
string myDate = Convert.ToDateTime("11-09-2012 5:08:31 PM").ToString("MM/dd/yyyy"
                                                  ,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But as you don't want result in `String`, you can use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) method.

```
DateTime parsedDate = DateTime.ParseExact("11-09-2012 5:08:31 PM", 
                                          "MM/dd/yyyy", 
                                          CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 1):

**SQL SERVER :**

Do like this for [MM/DD/YYYY] format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST('11-09-2012 5:08:31 PM' AS DATETIME), 101) AS [MM/DD/YYYY]
```

Similary, if you want to convert in [DD/MM/YYYY] format, you can do like this

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), CAST('11-09-2012 5:08:31 PM' AS DATETIME), 103) AS [DD/MM/YYYY]
```

---

**C#**

In C#, you simply do like this:

```
string formattedDt= Convert.ToDateTime("11-09-2012 5:08:31 PM")
                           .ToString("MM/dd/yyyy",CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

In c# you should be able to use the [method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.toshortdatestring.aspx):

```
DateTime.ToShortDateString();
```

Or even:

```
DateTime.Now.Date -- will produce just the date
```

Note from MSDN:

> The string returned by the ToShortDateString method is
>   culture-sensitive. It reflects the pattern defined by the current
>   culture's DateTimeFormatInfo object. For example, for the en-US
>   culture, the standard short date pattern is "M/d/yyyy"; for the de-DE
>   culture, it is "dd.MM.yyyy"; for the ja-JP culture, it is "yyyy/M/d".
>   The specific format string on a particular computer can also be
>   customized so that it differs from the standard short date format
>   string.

Comment: Note that this is culture-dependent, so if you always want `MM/dd/yyyy` and your code might possibly be run in another culture, you'll need to be more specific.

Comment: @TimS. that is why I provided a link to the method but I added a note about it.

Answer (score 0):

```
string date = "11-09-2012 5:08:31 PM";
string newDate = DateTime.Parse(date).ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample code using Date time parse and for more information you can visit the link [C-sharp date time formats](http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/)

```
string inputString = "11/08/2012";
DateTime dt = DateTime.MinValue;
try {
dt = DateTime.Parse(inputString);    
} 
catch (Exception ex) {
// handle the exception however you like.
return;
}
string formattedDate = String.Format("{0:MMM d, yyyy}", dt);
```